# Trying create 2D array of double and 1D array of String from the same file JAVA

Tags: java, arrays

Hey there I'm new to JAVA and am pretty stuck with my code. I am trying to read a file and make a 2D array of doubles and 1D array of string from the same file.

The file is set up like this with 75 rows:

1.2, 2.3, 3.4, 4.5, bob

5.6, 6.7, 7.8, 8.9, joe

This is what I have written so far:

```
import java.util.Scanner;
import java.io.*;

public class NearestNeighbor 
{
static String[] irisClass;
static int x=0;
static int y=0;
static double[][] measurement= new double [75][75];

public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException
{
    System.out.print("\nEnter the name of training file: ");
    Scanner input = new Scanner (System.in);
    String fileName = input.nextLine();
    File f = new File(fileName);
    Scanner fileScan = new Scanner(f);

    int row = 0;


    while (fileScan.hasNext())
    {
        row++;
        String line = fileScan.nextLine();

        String[] values = line.split(",");

        for (String str : values)
        {
            double str_double = Double.parseDouble(str);
            String s = fileScan.nextLine();
            measurement[x][y]=str_double;
            System.out.println(measurement[x][y] + " "+ s);
            y=y+1;
        }
        System.out.println("");
        x=x+1;

    }
}
```

This is what comes up when I run the code:

```
    Enter the name of training file: train.csv
   5.0 5.0,3.4,1.6,0.4,Iris-setosa
   Exception in thread "main" 3.0 5.2,3.5,1.5,0.2,Iris-setosa
   1.6 5.2,3.4,1.4,0.2,Iris-setosa
   0.2 4.7,3.2,1.6,0.2,Iris-setosa
    java.lang.NumberFormatException: For input string: "Iris-setosa"
at sun.misc.FloatingDecimal.readJavaFormatString(Unknown Source)
at sun.misc.FloatingDecimal.parseDouble(Unknown Source)
at java.lang.Double.parseDouble(Unknown Source)
at project.NearestNeighbor.main(NearestNeighbor.java:43)
```

How do I fix this problem? Any advice would be helpful. I did look at various answers and tried multiple things but I cannot seem to fix it.  THANKS IN ADVANCE

Comment: java.lang.NumberFormatException means, that you try to parse a String ( or another object) into an double, that cant be parsed into a double. For example, you cant parse the string "Hi" into a double, but strings like "0.4". In line 43, you try this.

Comment: try{
            double str_double = Double.parseDouble(str);
        }catch (Exception e){
            System.out.println(str+" is not a number");
        }

Comment: Tried your suggestion, now its sending it all to that exception

Comment: *"Tried your suggestion"* Tip: Add @Donatic (or whoever, the `@` is important) to *notify* the person of a new comment.